# Strange StretchBlt behaviour in right to left mode

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

In my application I'm drawing a bitmap in all fammilar and usual way using StretchBlt:

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInst, L"NewBitmapImage.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
StretchBlt(hdc, 100, 185, 100, 50, hdcMem, 0, 0, 100, 50, SRCCOPY);
```

It all works fine until WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL style is used for the main application window which results in the image width getting cropped by 1px. So, the problem only occurs when source width == destination width and when RTL style is used.
Is it a bug in StretchBlt or am I just not using it correctly?

Comment: Maybe, low odds.  It is however not very fammilar code.  No error checking and not restoring the device context is asking for trouble.  Is it actually getting cropped (column missing) or just stretched to 99 pixels?  Aero enabled?  What Windows version?

Comment: Why use `StretchBlt` if source/target dimensions are the same?

Comment: I have excluded all the error checking, context restoring etc from the code for simplicity. The image is getting cropped by 1px, i.e. 1px is missing from the right. I'm running it in Win7 x64 and compiling in VS2010. I know I can use BitBlt but it should still work with StretchBlt